# PHP array not showing

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, alert

I have this JS inside my php code:

```
echo " for (var i = 0; i<length; i++){
         alert('array[i]');

}";
```

Assuming all variables were defined and initialized, i'm not getting any output from the alert.

However, if i replace `array[i]` with `array[2]`, I get that value alerted.

any advice?

Comment: yes length was defined in my php code

Comment: How do you define array?

Comment: @MESSIAH none helped. Still not alerting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated variant:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { 
  $storeArray[] = $row['DayNum']; 
} 
$length = count($storeArray); 

for($i=0; $i < $length; $i++) { 
    echo "alert(".$storeArray[$i].");";
}
```

Comment: Tried this before, didn't work. Forgot to mention that the array is actually a php variable being called in the js code

Comment: Can you show us what variables you have and how you define them?

Comment: while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $storeArray[] =  $row['DayNum']; }
   $length = count($storeArray);
  
  

echo " function test() {
  for( var i=0; i< $length; i++){
   alert('$storeArray[i]');
  }
   
 } 
  ";

Comment: Thanks, it worked! But is there anyway I could include this in a javascript function instead?

Comment: Sure. echo "function showAlert() { "; for($i=0; $i < $length; $i++) { 
    echo "alert(".$storeArray[$i].");"; 
} echo "}";

Answer (score 1):

You need a script tag..Its not possible to alert something the way you are doing it.

```
<script>//write your javascript here</script>
```

Example:

```
 <?php
        function alert($myArray) 
        {
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("' . $myArray . '"); </script>';
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: I'm calling the php file using js: <script type="text/javascript" src="load2.php"> </script>

Answer (score 1):

Can it be length is not defined and you think it's giving you the array lenght? in that case you should have `i < array.length` otherwise length is thought to be a variable.

Check also that `array[i]` being an "array" where you get the values from in the for loop you don't need the `'`. Just write `alert(array[i]);`

Answer (score 0):

`alert('array[i]')` in this part JavaScript not execute array[i] as variable, instead, it prints it as string because its enclosed with single quota, change it to:

```
echo '<script>';
echo '
for (var i = 0; i<length; i++){
         alert(array[i]);

}
';
echo '</script>';
```

Comment: the arrayp[] is actually a php variable. I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo "<script> for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++){alert(array[i]);} </script>"; ?>
```